# Mixing JQuery click events with a JQuery post

Tags: jquery, events, post, click

I have a table (checkers game board) of id'ed td elements. I want to construct some JQuery code that does something like this

1. Get the id of a clicked td element, set it as "from" if it is empty
2. Get the id of a clicked td element, set it as "to" if "from" is filled
3. Post the "from" and "to" ids to the server, with a board object representing the board state

I've done a few tutorials, but I haven't been able to piece this together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1 & 2 you will want to use a jQuery selector that selects all the td elements in the table. Then you can use the click method to apply the same click handler to all. E.g.

```
$('#tableId').children('td').click(handler);
```

'handler' should be a function you've declared that does the logic e.g.

```
var from;

function handler(){
    if ( from ){
        $.post('url', { from : from, to : this.id });
        from = null;
    } else {
        from = this.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for getting the id's without creating a new jquery instance... good habit

Comment: Is there some case where writing `$(this).attr('id')` is better? I tend to use jQuery as a tool when I need it and I can't see why you _would_ create a new jQuery instance in this case?

Comment: If I'm going to be creating `$(this)` anyway (for instance to read a class) then I tend to use `$(this).attr('id')` in order to keep the code easier to read for other coders, even though it's a few characters longer and `$(this)[0].id` is marginally quicker.

Answer (score 2):

This will carry out the basic work

```
var from, to;
$("#board").on("click", "td", function() { // or, if using earlier than v1.7 jquery $("#board").delegate("td", "click", function()
   if (!from) {
       from = $(this).attr("id");
   } else {
       to = $(this).attr("id");
       $.post("/file.php", { 
           from: from, 
           to: to, 
           state : getBoardState()
       } );
       from = to = null;
   }
});
```

You'll need to write your `getBoardState()` function, which might be something like

```
function getBoardState() {
    var state = {};
    $("#board").find("td").each(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
         state[$this.attr("id")] = $this.hasClass("occupied");
    });
    return state;
}
```

Also, you need to be careful about disabling/handling clicks when waiting for the post to come back from the server

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly what you wanted, but this is what I understood from your explanation:

```
var from = "";
var to = "";

$("td").click(function(){ // fires when you click on a td element. You could also use $(".some_class") for example
    if(from=="") { // if "from" is still empty
        from = $(this).attr('id'); // define as id of this element
    } else if(from!="") { // if "from" is already filled
        to = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("/file.php", { firstvar: from, secondvar: to } ); // posts variables "from" and "to" as "firstvar" and "secondvar"
        from = ""; // reset the variables
        to = "";
    }
});
```

You didn't say when the data should get postet, so I wrote it in the else, as I think you want to post it then..

In file.php you can get the data as `$_POST["firstvar"]` and `$_POST["secondvar"]`

You could also use [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/file.php',
    data: { firstvar: from, secondvar: to },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // the output of this file was saved in "data"
        // something you want to do on success
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert('there was an error');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The absolute basics are fairly easy to put together, this adds a  bit more logic that must pick "from" first and checks for children  Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/VW94F/

```
var $brd = $('#board').click(function(evt) {
    var $cell = $(evt.target).closest('td');

    if ($cell.children().length) {
        $('.from').removeClass('from');
        $cell.addClass('from');
        $brd.data('from', $cell[0].id);
    } else {
        if (!$('.from').length) {
            alert('Select "from" first');
            return;
        }
        $cell.addClass('.to');
        var to=$cell[0].id, from= $brd.data('from');
        $brd.data('to', to);
        $.post(url, {from: from,to: to},function(data) {
                // do something on ajax success   
        $brd.removeData()                     
         });
        alert('From: ' + from + '\n To:' + to)
        }
    })
```